# how to insert into another table with a trigger?

Tags: mysql, sql, triggers, insert, dolibarr

[anas01_notes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MCP4c.png)[anas01_propal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UHzY1.png)I will explain better because I was not very clear. I have 2 tables, the anas01_notes table in which there is a note_value field and another "visibility" field. The 2nd table which is anas01_propal has a field which is note_public. I want to create a trigger that makes sure that when my note has visibility at 1 then the content of note_value is inserted in the anas01_propal table in the note_public field.

```
`BEGIN
    IF NEW.visibility = 1
        ELSEIF NEW.item_type = "propal" THEN
            INSERT INTO anas01_propal
        ELSEIF NEW.item_type = "facture" THEN
            INSERT INTO anas01_facture
    END IF;
END`
```

MySQL a répondu : #1064 - Erreur de syntaxe près de 'ELSEIF NEW.item_type = "propal" THEN INSERT INTO anas01_propal ...' à la ligne 3

here be indulgent I begin please

Comment: Please check the syntax for insert commands in MySQL documentation [https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/insert.html]. Your insert queries seem to be incomplete

Answer (score 0):

Do you want nested `IF` statements?

```
BEGIN
    IF NEW.visibility = 1
        IF NEW.item_type = 'propal' THEN
            INSERT INTO anas01_propal . . . ;
        ELSEIF NEW.item_type = 'facture' THEN
            INSERT INTO anas01_facture . . l;
        END IF;
    END IF;
END;
```

Note:  Your `INSERT`s are incomplete.  Add the columns and values where the `. . .` are.

Comment: I have to write all the columns of my table or just the one that is affected by the insertion?

Comment: @Anascode . . . You have to write syntactically correct `insert` statements.  Your question doesn't have enough information to specify what those are.

Comment: @Anascode . . . That explanation belongs in the question, not in a comment.